# Case Statement to pull report first of every month

Tags: sql-server, date, case

I am trying to create a report wrapped in a case statement so that when it is the first of the month, the report will send, however, when it isn't, the data will be returned as blank. Am I on track with the code below? Thank you in advance for the help.

```
case when dateadd(mm,datediff(mm,0,getdate()),0) then (select * from table) else end
```

Comment: Is the report generation automated using win service, task, sql job etc?

Comment: `if (DAY(myDate) = 1)` ?

Comment: @Kritner `DAY(getdate())`

Comment: NO. CASE is an expression in t-sql. As such it can't control the logic flow, it is used the return the value from a single column. You also might want to take a look at this article. https://sqlblog.org/2011/09/20/bad-habits-to-kick-using-shorthand-with-date-time-operations

Comment: @SeanLange Thank you for the article. So looking at what they said, would it be better to use Declare for this?

Comment: How is declare going to help? You use declare to declare a variable. The point is that you should use the word "MONTH" instead of the shorthand "mm"

Comment: @SeanLange Ohh okay sounds good!

Comment: Another good Aaron Bertrand article is [Dirty Secrets of the CASE Expression](https://sqlperformance.com/2014/06/t-sql-queries/dirty-secrets-of-the-case-expression)

Comment: But realize that your whole approach is flawed here.

Comment: Why don't you use an `IF` statement instead? Can we see the whole query?